# How to show different time period on Sunday - Jquery datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I would like to set a specific time period only on Sunday. So every other day the 'allowTimes' is from 18:00 to 22:30 but on sunday its 12:30 till 20:30. I am searching solution from last two days but haven't found it.
 HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" id="date" name="txtDate" class="form-control"  placeholder="Date">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" id="time" name="txtTime" class="form-control" placeholder="Time">
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
//Time Picker
$('#time').datetimepicker({
  datepicker:false,
  format:'H:i',
  step:15,
  allowTimes:['18:00','18:15','18:30','18:45','19:00','19:15','19:30','19:45','20:00','20:15','20:30','20:45','21:00','21:15', '21:30', '21:45', '22:00', '22:15','22:30']
});

// Date Picker
$('#date').datetimepicker({
  timepicker:false,
  format:'d/m/Y',
});
```

Comment: Why don't you make a function which returns `true` or `false` if the date is in range. At max, it'll only take `O(1)` from the numbers i can see, which should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is trickier than it seems because [jQuery DateTimePicker](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) in an instance **and** the fact that once initialized, you can't change the options.

But there always is a walk-around!

The trick here is to "destroy" the instance on the time input when the day number changes *(0 for sunday to 6 for saturday)* and reinitialise it with the right schedule. Now if the selected time does not exist in the new schedule, force the user to re-select the time.

Looks simple? See the code:

```js
console.clear();

var schedule_week = ['18:00','18:15','18:30','18:45',
                     '19:00','19:15','19:30','19:45',
                     '20:00','20:15','20:30','20:45',
                     '21:00','21:15','21:30','21:45',
                     '22:00','22:15','22:30'];

var schedule_sunday = ['12:30','12:45',
                       '13:00','13:15','13:30','13:45',
                       '14:00','14:15','14:30','14:45',
                       '15:00','15:15','15:30','15:45',
                       '16:00','16:15','16:30','16:45',
                       '17:00','17:15','17:30','17:45', 
                       '18:00','18:15','18:30','18:45',
                       '19:00','19:15','19:30','19:45',
                       '20:00','20:15','20:30'
                      ];

var prev_dayNum;
var schedule_used = schedule_week;  // Use the week schedule by default.

// Function to initialise the time picker input.
function initTime(){
  $('#time').datetimepicker({
    datepicker:false,
    format:'H:i',
    step:15,
    allowTimes: schedule_used
  });
}
// On load time initialisation.
initTime();

// Initialise the date input.
$('#date').datetimepicker({
  timepicker:false,
  format:'d/m/Y',

  // On change callback
  onChangeDateTime:function(dp,$input){

    var dateVal = $input.val();
    var timeVal = $('#time').val();
    //console.log(dateVal +" - "+ (timeVal||"No Time"));

    // Because of the d/m/Y format, have to process the date a bit to get the day number.
    val = dateVal.split("/");
    var dayNum = new Date(val[2]+"/"+val[1]+"/"+val[0]).getDay();
    //console.log("dayNum: "+dayNum);

    // if dayNum is zero (sunday), use sunday schedule... Else use the week schedule.
    schedule_used = (dayNum == 0) ? schedule_sunday : schedule_week;

    // If the dayNum changed.
    if( prev_dayNum != dayNum  ){
      console.log("Changed day!");
      // Re-initialise datetimepicker
      $('#time').datetimepicker("destroy");
      initTime();

      // If the actual time value is not in schedule.
      if($.inArray(timeVal,schedule_used) == -1){
        console.log("Wrong time!");
        // Clear the time value.
        $('#time').val("");
        // Focus the time input so it's obvious the user has to re-select a time.
        $('#time').focus();
      }
    }
    // Keep this dayNum in memory for the next time.
    prev_dayNum = dayNum;
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" id="date" name="txtDate" class="form-control"  placeholder="Date">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" id="time" name="txtTime" class="form-control" placeholder="Time">
</div>
```

Now as you can see, the time schedule is different for sundays than the other days. And it "forces" the user to enter/re-enter a time **only** when what's entered does not fit the schedule.

I left the console logs uncommented in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/bxreRE?editors=0011).

Comment: Worked Perfectly. Thank you very much

Comment: I made a slight improvement... I added `prev_dayNum = dayNum;` to keep the day number in memory... I just forgot. ;)